# URL Rewrite: Wrong redirect first character

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I got the following rule in my .htaccess (no other rules before or after this one):

```
RewriteRule ^archive/([^/\.]+)/?$ /archive.php?letter=$1 [L]
```

What I need this rule to do is the following:

`mydomain/archive/letter` rewrite to: `mydomain/archive.php?letter=letter`

It works for all letters of the alphabet, except for a.

The result is, while browsing:

> mydomain/archive/b --> no redirect, shows page as it were archive.php?letter=b (correct)
>
> mydomain/archive/a --> redirect to: mydomain// (incorrect)

I searched high and low, but I can't see what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: From what you've got there I can't see where the `/archive/` part of the path needs to come into this at all - you're just picking it up from `archive.php` ... or is it that you want the URL to be `mydomain/archive/[a-z]` ?

Comment: Can you show your full .htaccess in question?

Comment: This is the whole .htaccess. @CD001 I want to pick it up from archive.php indeed.

Comment: It starts with "RewriteEngine on" on row 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason another rule after this one was interfering with the one in my question. I removed that one and it works now. So, the rule in the question is a working one :)